# Compatibility between TFS 2012 collection and TFS 2015

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

i got task to migrate TFS collection from 2012 to 2015 and I'm scared that something could go wrong because of different TFS versions.

I read some posts and TFS documentations and it's straight forward but nobody mention that migrating collection between TFS 2012 and 2015 is safe.

Does anyone have any experience with this particular problem?

Link to some post/docs that says for sure that it's safe would be great.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I hope this will help someone in the future.
I migrated TFS 2012 collection to TFS 2015 successfully. But you should pay attention on few things like(moving between express and enterprise versions, database compatibility level, that you dont't have database with the same name on destitantion sql server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to explain what you mean with "Safe". It is not going to break or lose your code, so in this regard it is safe.

There are somethings that may be affected, like the Scrum or the Agile templates, for example. IF they got an update. You will have to look into the versions and the changes, and what template was used in your projects.

Comment: By "Safe" i ment exacly what you explained in first paragraf. My biggest concern is that i don't lose code or some of the changesets. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a number of migration without big issues: plan some work in the Work Item area.
A suggestion when migrating from 2010/2 to 2013/5/7: avoid upgrading your Build Controllers or Agents. If you have custom activities they will probably break and need recompiling.

Migrating to 2018 poses a serious challenge: it does not support XAML builds anymore, so one should move to 2017.3 and redo the build in the new technology before going to 2018 and later.